# Web game developing with socketIO

Tags: php, javascript, html, socket.io

I'm new to web developing and web tehnologies. For learning I'm trying to cretate a multiplayer game with websocket. The game is "Make the bigger word" Here I write a code that get "random" letters from base to users and user who have a bigger word with that letter WIN.

I have a code but I have a seriuos problem with connecting with base via socket.io API

Code that give a letter for creating word:

```
<div id="s">STOP</div>

<div id="L1"></div>
<div id="L2"></div>
<div id="L3"></div>
<div id="L4"></div>
<div id="L5"></div>

$a="AGHBV";

v=setInterval(function(){for(i=0;i<6;i++){$("#L"+i).html(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26+65)))};},500);$("#s").click(function(){clearInterval(v);setTimeout(function(){for(j=0;j<$a.length;j++){$("#L"+(j+1)).html($a[j]);}},250);});
```

When user click on STOP div then they get the $a letters... so that is so easy when you get a$ from base via php but how to send this a$ from server to client via socket.io

for socket.io I have a some code but I doesnt know how need to exactly work.

Here is socket client file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:11px; font-family:arial; color:#444; }
        body { padding:20px; }
        #message-list { list-style-type:none; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid #999; padding:20px; }
        #message-list li { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; padding-bottom:2px; margin-bottom:5px; }
        code { font-family:courier; background:#eee; padding:2px 4px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Create SocketIO instance
        var socket = new io.Socket('localhost',{
            port: 8080
        });
        socket.connect(); 

        // Add a connect listener
        socket.on('connect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:green;">Client has connected to the server!</span>');
        });
        // Add a connect listener
        socket.on('message',function(data) {
            log('Received a message from the server:  ' + data);
        });
        // Add a disconnect listener
        socket.on('disconnect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:red;">The client has disconnected!</span>');
        });

        // Sends a message to the server via sockets
        function sendMessageToServer(message) {
            socket.send(message);
            log('<span style="color:#888">Sending "' + message + '" to the server!</span>');
        }

        // Outputs to console and list
        function log(message) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = message;
            document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
        }

        /*
        // Create a socket instance
        socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

        // Open the socket
        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('Socket opened on client side',event);

            // Listen for messages
            socket.onmessage = function(event) {
                console.log('Client received a message',event);
            };

            // Listen for socket closes
            socket.onclose = function(event) {
                console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
            };

        };
        */

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Messages will appear below (and in the console).</p><br />
    <ul id="message-list"></ul>
    <ul style="margin:20px 0 0 20px;">
        <li>Type <code>socket.disconnect()</code> to disconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>socket.connect()</code> to reconnect</li>
        <li>Type <code>sendMessageToServer('Your Message')</code> to send a message to the server</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is socket server file:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 

    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

    // Create periodical which ends a message to the client every 5 seconds
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        client.send('This is a message from the server!  ' + new Date().getTime());
    },5000);

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

});
```

What I need to do to get what I need. How to implement socketIO in my script to get a$ from server to client ... how to do that server send a a$ from base to client???

(sorry for my english, i'm beginer to web tech. so sorry about a trivial question)

Comment: also here is working version : http://jsfiddle.net/Hx28c/3/

Comment: nobody know?         ...

Comment: you basically said, here is all my code, what is wrong with it? typically you would have a very specific question, with only relevant code snippets. this is a very vague question with a novel of code to look through.

Comment: I'm for first time work with socketIO and I really dont know how to implement into my code. also I try to find the answer all over the net but I couldnt, sorry for that question, I know that is not specific... but I need only one thing. to make the server to send a data to client with example to better learn I and developers here!

Comment: What I need to do, to server send a data ($a) to client voa socket.IO api

Comment: try following one of the many tutorials... https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=8DJvqYLbNOlLOdk4nPBp5Q&cp=11&gs_id=18&xhr=t&q=socket.io+tutorial&pf=p&rlz=1C2CHME_enUS361&sclient=psy-ab&oq=socket.io+t&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=160a46efcf63646c&biw=1440&bih=781

Comment: ok, I know that but its not a answer

Comment: Doesn't know much of the web for a guy named Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an good example on how send messages from server to client and client to server. This article will be suitable for you because you have a game with multiple clients. So that I think the best option would be to broadcast messages among the client.

In Server..

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Socket Created...');

      socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('messageRecieve', data);
    });
});
```

In client,

```
   socket.on('messageRecieve', function (data) {//receive broadcasted message from server
        AppendMessage(data.msg);
    });

     function SendMessage() {// sends the message from client to the server may be on click
        var message = document.getElementById('text').value;
        socket.emit('sendMessage', { msg: message });
        AppendMessage(message);
    }
```

Here is more detail on this , http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2012/04/real-time-web-sample-using-socketio-and.html

Comment: so I only need to change my code with this code and then will be work

Comment: My be you have to arrange this in ur way.. :)

Comment: ok,i will try but i dont think so... where i need to add this to my code, please help... and sorry for boring you but i'm so interesting in this tehnology

Comment: hey.. You need to go through some tutorial   to start. Please go through the tutorial I have given. And read basics here http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Ok, but can I install scket.io on shared hosting...what i'm need first, node.js on server?

Comment: you can install iis node http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx